# Why does coffescript conditional assignment not work in function calls?

Tags: coffeescript

I can do

```
fun = if state then "a" else "b"
somefunction(fun, "param")
```

However I cannot do

```
somefunction(if state then "a" else "b", "param")
```

in Coffee 1.8.0. Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried `somefunction((if state then "a" else "b"), "param")` ? What does "cannot do" mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you. When it comes to CoffeeScript I stuck time and again without seeing the obvious solutions...